# Is there a way to display the date in power reserve mode on the Apple Watch Series 2?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I constantly forget to charge my watch on time so 25% of the time I use it in power reserve mode.  It kind of bothers me that there's only the time shown.

I searched around in the watch and iPhone settings and also in other communities but didn't found an answer.

I have the latest watchOS running in Series 2.

Does anyone know if the watch can show the date in power reserve mode?

Comment: The date should be shown, as it’s basic, important, and would take negligible power to keep track of, even with no data connection and everything else turned off.  But as others have already said, Apple didn’t include it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power Reserve mode the goal is to save battery as you are on low power.

This shuts down all functionally except the time which is displayed by pressing the button. The time is more important than the date in most cases.

As this is by design and a preset feature it can’t be changed.

> All Apple Watch functionality shuts down except the ability to keep and display the time, which can only be displayed by pressing the side button on the watch. The time displays for six seconds.

([Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/236100/how-to-enable-and-disable-power-reserve-on-apple-watch/amp/))

Answer (score 1):

Power Reserve mode disables all the 'smart' features of the Apple Watch and only displays the time.  This is by design and can't be changed

If you're in Power Reserve mode, that means you don't want to display anything that could possibly increase the power usage.  The date is one of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to show the current date in Power Reserve Mode - only the current time.